# How to edit apalike2.bst file so I can get printed retrieved date and url in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

I was wondering if there's any way I can edit the `apalike2.bst` file so I can get printed the `retrieved date` and `url` (with `hyperlink`) on my bibliography. This is for my thesis, I have over 150 articles cited. I'm writing on TeXmaker using Mendeley Desktop and JabRef (V. 2.10) in order to do it.

For example, I have this web page:

```
@Misc{FOXNEWS2014,
  Title                    = {{Forest fire kills 16, destroys 500 homes in Chile city}},
  Author                   = {FOXNEWS},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Retrieved date           = {19 de Junio, 2015},
  Url                      = {http://www.foxnews.com/world/2014/04/13/forest-fire-destroys-at-least-150-homes-sparks-evacuations-in-chilean-city/}
}
```

And I'd like to have it like this:

> FOXNEWS. (2014). Forest fire kills 16, destroys 500 homes in Chile
>   city.   Retrieved 19 de Junio, 2015, from
>   http://www.foxnews.com/world/2014/04/13/forest-fire-destroys-at-least-150-homes-sparks-evacuations-in-chilean-city/

Instead, when I compile on Texmaker I get:

> FOXNEWS (2014). Forest fire kills 16, destroys 500 homes in Chile
>   city.

I'd be really greateful if you guys can help me out on this.

Greetings from Chile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apalike2` bibliography style was last updated in 1989, and it's thus not set up to do anything with fields named `url` and `RetrievedDate`. I therefore suggest you edit the entry so that the `note` field contains the relevant information.

```
@Misc{FOXNEWS2014,
  Title                    = {{Forest fire kills 16, destroys 500 homes in Chile city}},
  Author                   = {FOXNEWS},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Note                     = {Retrieved 19 de Junio, 2015 from \url{http://www.foxnews.com/world/2014/04/13/forest-fire-destroys-at-least-150-homes-sparks-evacuations-in-chilean-city/}},
}
```

Do make sure the `url` package is loaded as well, with the option `hyphens`.

Comment: thank you for that quick answer. But as I was saying, I have over 150 articles/web pages.. If I don't get an easier or more efficient solution, Id go for that option. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeV - Any chance you can switch to a more modern bibliography style, i.e, one that at least recognizes the field name `url`?

Comment: I could, yes. But to be honest, I really love the way apalike2 citation is printed. I could just put the brackets and a number, but I don't like it at all.. But I think I'll take your advice and do it manually, in the 'note' section. I still got enough time. Thank you sir.